# How to show only progress information with youtube-dl?

Tags: python, terminal, youtube-dl

I'm making a script with python that download some videos from a page, and there's some Youtube videos, so I'm using youtube-dl to download them.

The problem is that the terminal is so dirty with all informations, I want to hide them. Hide everything, the path of save, the current status, but keep only the progress information. If I set the **quiet mode** to **True**, the progress information don't appear.

**My code:**

```
def ytbDown(path, name, url):
ydl_opts = {
        'outtmpl': path + name,
        'format': 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best',
        'quiet': False,
        'warnings': 'no-warnings'}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
```

If I run the script with that configuration, the terminal appears this way:
[image]

If I set the quiet mode to True, nothing appears, but I don't wanna this. I wanna keep **only** the progress status (download porcentage, download speed, etc)

There's a way to do this?
Thanks for all the help, I'm using Python 3 and Windows 7

Comment: i think you are looking for this  flag `--console-title`  Display progress in console titlebar

Comment: Maybe this could work, but how I pass this argument? I mean:
'anyname': 'console-title'?
Sorry, I'm new with youtube-dl, I don't know so much about the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

def my_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'downloading':
        print ("downloading "+ str(round(float(d['downloaded_bytes'])/float(d['total_bytes'])*100,1))+"%")
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
        filename=d['filename']
        print(filename)

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestvideo[width<=1080]+bestaudio/best',
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook]
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(sys.argv[1:])
```

Can replace sys.argv[1:] with `["www.youtube.com/....."]`, including the square brackets

reference youtube-dl documentation on embedding

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl