# Is there a way to include download progress bars from rich while logging from youtube-dl?

Tags: python, logging, youtube-dl, rich

I'm making a script that mass downloads youtube videos from a text file, and wanted to spice up the console logging a bit with rich. However, while the system that I have does output using rich, it doesn't have progress bars for the download.

This is the current state of the code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from rich.logging import RichHandler
import logging
import youtube_dl

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,   format="%(message)s",  datefmt="[%X]",
    handlers=[RichHandler(level=logging.DEBUG, rich_tracebacks=True, markup=True ) ]
) 
log = logging.getLogger('rich')
def load(id): 
    address = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + id
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'wav',
            'preferredquality': '192'
        }],
        'outtmpl': 'audio/%(id)s.wav',
        "logger": log,
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([address])
```

I was wondering if there was anyway to incercept the download portion of the logging to be replaced with some sort of progress bar.

Comment: You could use a progress hook [as specified in the README](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl).

Answer (score 0):

There is way of course, but it's a bit tricky. See this discussion:
[How to show only progress information with youtube-dl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63025605/how-to-show-only-progress-information-with-youtube-dl)

Following code uses rich bar while downloading audio:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
from rich.progress import track

bar = False 
barvalues = []  
def updatebar(d, finish=False):
    ## rich rogress bar
    if finish and bar:
       100 in bar # you need to finish 'manually'
       # Yeah new song!
    elif bar:
        p = int(round( float(d['downloaded_bytes']) / float(d['total_bytes']) *100))
        if p in range(100) and (not p in barvalues):
            barvalues.append(p) # prevent repeatin' otherwise fails
            int(p) in bar # display progress
    else:
        print("Bar not declared")

def hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
        global bar
        updatebar(d, True)
        bar = False
        print("Converting ..")
    elif d['status'] == 'downloading':
        updatebar(d)

opts = {
    'cachedir': False, # avoid http 403: forbidden (sometimes anyway happens)
    'rm_cachedir': True, # avoid http 403: forbidden
    'outtmpl': 'mypath/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': '{}'.format("mp3"),
        'preferredquality': '{}'.format("320"),
    }],
    'progress_hooks': [hook]
}

def download(src):
    global bar, barvalues
    barvalues = [] # dot't forget to update
    bar = track(range(100), description="")
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(opts) as ytdl:
        title = ytdl.extract_info(src, download=False).get('title', None)
        print("\nDownloading .. " + title)
        ytdl.cache.remove() # Important! avoid http 403: forbidden
        ytdl.download([src])
```

Comment: Maybe global variable is not the best idea, but I think U can make it bette

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a progress bar with rich while downloading the videos using youtube_dl. You need to use `rich.progress` to display the progress bar, and then customise youtube_dl's progress hooks to update the progress bar.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from rich.logging import RichHandler
from rich.progress import Progress
import logging
import youtube_dl

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s", datefmt="[%X]",
    handlers=[RichHandler(level=logging.DEBUG, rich_tracebacks=True, markup=True)]
)
log = logging.getLogger('rich')

def progress_hook(d, progress, task_id):
    if d['status'] == 'downloading':
        progress.update(task_id, advance=d['downloaded_bytes'])
    elif d['status'] == 'finished':
        progress.stop()

def load(id):
    with Progress() as progress:
        task_id = progress.add_task("[cyan]Downloading...", total=100)

        address = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + id
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'wav',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
            'outtmpl': 'audio/%(id)s.wav',
            "logger": log,
            'progress_hooks': [lambda d: progress_hook(d, progress, task_id)],
        }

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download([address])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # replace BAfOGBojiEU with your ID
    load('BAfOGBojiEU')
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

PS: I had to apply this fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/75602237/561766 to get youtube-dl to not throw an error.