# Error: Unable to extract uploader id - Youtube, Discord.py

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, youtube-dl

I have a very powerful bot in discord (discord.py, PYTHON) and it can play music in voice channels. It gets the music from youtube (youtube_dl). It **worked perfectly before** but now it doesn't want to work with any video.
I tried updating youtube_dl but it still doesn't work
I searched everywhere but I still can't find a answer that might help me.

This is the Error: `Error: Unable to extract uploader id`

After and before the error log there is no more information.
Can anyone help?

I will leave some of the code that I use for my bot...
The youtube setup settings:

```
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''


ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0',  # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn',
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')
        self.duration = data.get('duration')
        self.image = data.get("thumbnails")[0]["url"]
    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))
        #print(data)

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]
        #print(data["thumbnails"][0]["url"])
        #print(data["duration"])
        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)
```

Approximately the command to run the audio (from my bot):

```
sessionChanel = message.author.voice.channel
await sessionChannel.connect()
url = matched.group(1)
player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=client.loop, stream=True)
sessionChannel.guild.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print(
                                       f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)
```

Comment: I'm still getting this error in July, with youtube-dl installed from pip.

Comment: Youtube-dl for some reason has stopped updating their libraries. So use for now yt-dlp. Read the rest of the answers, maybe something can help you

Comment: Yes, using yt-dlp worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This is a known issue, fixed in Master. For a temporary fix,

```
python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/archive/master.tar.gz
```

This installs tha master version. Run it through the command-line

```
yt-dlp URL
```

where URL is the URL of the video you want. See `yt-dlp --help` for all options. It should just work without errors.

If you're using it as a module,

```
import yt_dlp as youtube_dl
```

might fix your problems (though there could be API changes that break your code; I don't know which version of `yt_dlp` you were using etc).

Comment: I installed it but the python code dosn't finds it

Comment: sudo snap install yt-dlp

Comment: I am using master (6fece0a96b3cd8677f5c1185a57c6e21403fcb44), 2023-03-14, and the problem is _not_ solved.

Comment: worked for me on a mac air, thank you

Answer (score 68):

I solved it temporarily (`v2021.12.17`) until there's a new update,
by editing file:
`your/path/to/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py`

Example path:

- If installed via PIP: `~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py`
- If installed via brew: `/usr/local/Cellar/youtube-dl/2021.12.17/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py`

Line number(~): 1794 and add the option `fatal=False`

[image]

Before:

```py
'uploader_id': self._search_regex(r'/(?:channel|user)/([^/?&#]+)', owner_profile_url, 'uploader id') if owner_profile_url else None
```

After:

```py
'uploader_id': self._search_regex(r'/(?:channel|user)/([^/?&#]+)', owner_profile_url, 'uploader id', fatal=False) if owner_profile_url else None
```

This converts it from critical (which exits the script) to a warning (which simply continues)

Comment: this solved it for me while I'm waiting for homebrew to pick up the update from master

Comment: How did you realized that this could save the run? Some tip do share?

Comment: @DanielBandeira i just scanned the internet for a solution, read many posts and its comments, kept this post open that incase i'll find a solution *that works* i'll post the answer here as well ... once I found a comment that gave this solution - i shared it here for others ...

Comment: Thanks. I think it's nice to mention that it's line 1794 of version 2021.12.17 (last one at this time). Just add the `fatal=False` option.

Comment: @Ricky Levi  Thanks for the solution! This solved the problem for me. I can confirm that I downloaded the latest available version n Github on March 18th 2023 and at line n° 1794 as you mentioned, by adding fatal=False, the issue was resolved.

Comment: Had to search for that path (installed via brew):
`/usr/local/Cellar/youtube-dl/2021.12.17/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor`

Comment: Thanks a lot this fixes the issue for me too.

Comment: I found `youtube.py` with path with [python -m site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46071447/1705829) and then found the `venv` folder with `site-packages`

Answer (score 25):

For everyone using youtube_dl and wondering how to solve this issue without using another library like `ytdlp`: First uninstall youtube_dl with `pip uninstall youtube_dl` then install the master branch of youtube_dl from their github with `pip install git+https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl.git@master#egg=youtube_dl`.
You need git for this, download it [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads). Ive tested it and it works actually.

**Edit:**

Youtube_dl isn't maintained anymore, so I would recommend to use [ytdlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp), also see this [link](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#differences-in-default-behavior) for differences between yt-dl and ytdlp in terms of the default behavior

Comment: I notice the use of "youtube-dl" and "youtube_dl", are these typos or interchangeable or distinctly separate entities ?

Comment: Aye, it works as advertised. I got a bit confused because `Youtube-dl` reports itself as the 'broken' 2021.12.17 version (!), but it _is_ a much more recent one. The `Youtube-dl` repo maintainers really need to fix _that_ on `master`! :-) Thanks for sharing your solution/fix.

Comment: np and yes you are right.

Comment: @Dee underscores and hyphens are interchangeable for `pip`. Python packages are supposed to use hyphens instead of underscores [(source)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names). But because of the confusion, both will work. Pypi shows "youtube_dl" but `pip list` shows "youtube-dl" regardless of how you installed it.

Answer (score 15):

This fixed (for Ubuntu/Linux):

1. install git (if not installed | check command: $ git --version)

```
sudo apt install git
```

2. install pip (Python package manager, if not installed)

```
sudo apt install pip
```

3. reinstall youtube-dl directly from git repository

```
sudo pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall "git+https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl.git"
```

Comment: worked for me on ubuntu

Comment: Worked on windows as well with pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall "git+https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl.git"

Answer (score 9):

They are aware of and fixed this problem, you can check this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/issues/6253).

If you wanna fix it quickly, you can use [this](https://github.com/ytdl-patched/yt-dlp/releases/tag/2023.02.17.334) package. Or just wait for a new release, it's up to you.

Comment: Will I need to change my entire python code so it will work with yt-dlp?

Answer (score 1):

```
python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/archive/master.tar.gz
```

If the installed location is not added to *PATH* try to specify the location.

```
python3 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/yt-dlp --no-check-certificate "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvkQ1B3FBqA"
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
    ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'extractor_retries': 'auto',
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
```

add `extractor_retries` works perfect with me :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this:

```
    ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': '%(id)s%(ext)s'})
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    import youtube_dl
    ydl_opts = {
         'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192'
        }],
        'postprocessor_args': [
            '-ar', '16000'
        ],
        'prefer_ffmpeg': True,
        'keepvideo': True
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download(['link'])

use this:
from pytube import YouTube
import os

yt = YouTube('link')

video = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()

out_file = video.download(output_path=".")

base, ext = os.path.splitext(out_file)
new_file = base + '.mp3'
os.rename(out_file, new_file)
```

Above code will definitely run.

Answer (score 0):

To install the latest version with Homebrew:

```
brew uninstall youtube-dl
brew install --HEAD youtube-dl
```

`--HEAD` is what matters here, it takes the latest version on the repository.

cf. [the Homebrew man page](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage)