# Error: Unable to extract uploader id (yt-dlp Library)

Tags: python, ios, yt-dlp

I'm running yt-dlp in an iOS App, and 2 days ago they just fixed it because of a YouTube code change:
https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/issues/6247

The problem is that I already updated from the yt-dlp library file from the new releases:
https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases

And I'm getting exactly the same error:
[image]

Anything that I'm missing?

Comment: You didn't specify what version you updated to. It supposedly is fixed in 2023.02.17.334 upwards.

Comment: I can confirm that this hickup has been fixed with 2023-02-17.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was fixed in Current version: 2023.02.17

Comment: Where y'all getting these versions from? Official sources like PyPI and youtube-dl.org still list 2021.* as the "latest" released version. (Edit: ohhh, you're talking about a *fork*. I see.)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to install the yt-dlp master. They solved the problem there. You can do this with `pip install --force-reinstall https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/archive/master.tar.gz`

If you are willing to use youtube-dl, you can download the `[Youtube-dl-master][1]` package and build it manually (what I did - worked fine). Also there the problem was solved in the master.

You can see a variety of solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75495800/error-unable-to-extract-uploader-id-youtube-discord-py).

Successfully!

Answer (score 0):

@mtraceur, when i installed 'yt-dlp' from: https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp, I got python version error, saying I need Python 3.7> when 2.7x is what's available from openSuSE 15.5 repos, so I downloaded yt-dlp.rpm from opensuse software: https://software.opensuse.org/
added to local repo and installed via zypper.
it works for me and is release 2023-02-17

also installed an instance from Packman.gwd.de
it too works on Leap 15.5 python.
Landis.