# error video using youtube-dl; "Unable to extract uploader id"

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-dl, ytdl, yt-dlp

i want download video from youtube using youtube-dl library

this my code:

```py
import youtube_dl

video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9Fcgdlw-Nc"

desired_format = 'mp4'

ydl_opts = {
    'format': desired_format,
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([video_url])
```

But i get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\sepeh\Desktop\Bot> & "C:/Program Files/Python39/python.exe" c:/Users/sepeh/Desktop/Bot/main.py
[youtube] w9Fcgdlw-Nc: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sepeh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 815, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sepeh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 836, in __extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
  File "C:\Users\sepeh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 534, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
  File "C:\Users\sepeh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py", line 1794, in _real_extract
    'uploader_id': self._search_regex(r'/(?:channel|user)/([^/?&#]+)', owner_profile_url, 'uploader id') if owner_profile_url else None,
  File "C:\Users\sepeh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 1012, in _search_regex
    raise RegexNotFoundError('Unable to extract %s' % _name)
youtube_dl.utils.RegexNotFoundError: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\sepeh\Desktop\Bot\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    ydl.download(["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9Fcgdlw-Nc"])
  File "C:\Users\sepeh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 2068, in download
    res = self.extract_info(
  File "C:\Users\sepeh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 808, in extract_info
    return self.__extract_info(url, ie, download, extra_info, process)
  File "C:\Users\sepeh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 824, in wrapper
    self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "C:\Users\sepeh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 628, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "C:\Users\sepeh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 598, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
PS C:\Users\sepeh\Desktop\Bot>
```

What i do?

When I asked ChatGPT for help, it gave me 2 solutions:

- Upgrading the library `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`
- Bug report on the official website of the library

But if there was such a bug, everyone would be involved in it now.
I think the problem is on my side...

Comment: As I experience the same issue, I recommend moving to [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) which does not have this issue.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75495800/error-unable-to-extract-uploader-id-youtube-discord-py) answer your question?